# Regex to select only inner braces ignoring outer braces

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, regex, html

I have a text which contains square braces. I am trying to write a regex which selects only the inner square braces.

For this text `[Interim Review[s]] are g[iv]en [by m[a]in head] and [no one e[lse has] th]e access`

The regex must look like

[Interim Review`[s]`] are g[iv]en [by m`[a]`in head] and [no one e`[lse has]` th]e access

Please help. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### [`\[([^[\]]*)\].*?]`](https://regex101.com/r/xR0wM3/7)

This is very specific to the example you've provided.

Comment: \[[^[\]]*\] This is working. But the sqaure brace is also getting selected along with the text. My requirement is that only the text inside the square brace must be selected but the brace

Comment: @rjirji Edited - see above.

Comment: @rjirji Also, if you don't want empty brackets, change  that asterisk `*` to `+`

Comment: actually I haven't noticed there is one more issue. It must not accept the braces which do not have outer braces. It should highlight only the inner braces having the outer braces. But not the braces which do not have outer braces.

Comment: @rjirji You may try the new one, but I must mention that regex codes should always be specific to the given problem at hand. Since I don't know what data you're trying to find this might still need more edits. So, either update your question with some sample data or experiment with the code yourself, until you succeed.

Comment: I have changed my question. You can see that the inner brace which is having outer brace must be highlighted. The one which has only a single brace without outer brace must not be highlighted. You can see in the format given in the question that in g[iv]en [iv] must not be highlighted as it does not have an outer brace.

Comment: why so just use like this \\[[^\\[]+?]

Comment: Please see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38782183/regex-which-identified-words-with-tags

Comment: @RenaeLider please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38869675/correction-in-regex

Answer (score 0):

this should work `\[[^\[]+?]` or `(\[?[^\[]+[^\]?]\])`

Answer (score -1):

here it is, it captures `[inside]`

```
/\[[\w ]\]/g
```

or with capturing only content of the square brackets [`content`] in the groups.

```
/\[([\w ])\]/g
```

Comment: The first one is working only for the case where there are no spaces. But the inner square brace may contain space too. See here https://regex101.com/r/xR0wM3/2. The last inner brace consists space between a word which is not highlighted in regex